# Why aren't my comments highlighted correctly?

Tags: discussion, bug, syntax-highlighting

From my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31438368/swift-whats-the-difference-between-metatype-type-and-self/41709040#41709040).

The last two lines. The comment colors have different colors. Is that a bug?

[image]

Comment: Looks like the swift comment parser is off; you'd need to report that to the Prettify project (see the duplicate).

Comment: I looked into the list of supported languages. Obviously it's supported. You simply mean that Prettify server is down? You mean like they're **possibly** doing some updates on 4th of July and it's down and all will be good tomorrow?